# What's the difference in threaded and threadless headset and stem

Tags: headset, stem

What's the difference in threadless and threaded headsets and stems? Why change it? is it because it's easier for maintenance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminology index - a list of bike part names and cycling concepts](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts)

Comment: This is very easy to look up via a Google search, but for pointers: [This sites's Terminology Index](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/10078) and this [Sheldon Brown page](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/brandt/threadless-headset.html).

Comment: I was meaning to ask this today! Great minds.. At least the why of it.

Comment: Mainly disease of maintenance.  Makes the old and new incompatible, encouraging folks to buy new stuff.

Comment: Money is always a motivating factor - need to make and stock fewer different sizes has a huge effect on inventory costs.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I don't see any answer on the terminology page, except for stating what a stem is. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I thought I was linking to the *headset* entry, which has info on threaded vs threadless.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Gotcha. The "duplicate" system strips out the "answer" part of the link, since it didn't imagine that a question could ever be a duplicate of an answer. The link in your manual comment is also to the question, rather than the answer. I agree that the headset answer does cover this question (I was mislead into looking for "stem").

Comment: @DavidRicherby I updated the OP's question. The headset is really what is threaded, and used with a quill stem.

Comment: Really, I think the Headset and Stem descriptions in the terminology index explain the mechanical differences, but not the why or pro/con of threaded vs threadless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a page on here explaining the basics, [Terminology index - a list of bike part names and cycling concepts](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/10078#10078)

There are some advantages for maintenance, it is simpler and faster to adjust the bearing preload with the central bolt through the top cap, rather than using the lockrings on a threaded headset. Threadless also requires only hex keys to adjust, as opposed to specific lockring spanners.

The overall system of threadless headset and clamp on stem is probably lighter and stiffer, but I'm guessing... if true it's a big reason! i.e. lighter weight and better steering.

The larger stem with threadless headset allows material for the modern handlebar clamp with four bolts, enabling you to remove the whole handlebar assembly easily. It is able to achieve this without significant weight penalty. With a lot of quill stem designs, the clamp forces you to remove brake levers etc from the bar to remove the bar from the stem by sliding it through. There are two bolt clamp designs for quill stems but arguably 4 bolt clamps are a superior design.

With threaded, the quill stems have a tendency to get rusted in place, worsened by aluminium vs steel combinations, so rust or galvanic corrosion can prevent removal of the stem, thus adjustment or bearing servicing becomes impossible if a threaded headset is neglected for too long. This is less likely to be a problem with a threadless headset.

Also for threaded steerers, the steerer must be cut to fit the frame head tube and the headset stack height quite accurately. Replacement headsets must match this stack height quite closely to be compatible. Whilst this is an unusual occurrence, more significantly the fork/steerer tube cannot be re-used in a taller head tube on a different bike. Both these issues are more easily managed for a threadless system.

Hope that helps, no doubt there's more reasons than this!

Comment: The whole paragraph about handlebar ease of removal is irrelevant to the threadless/threaded topic. There are/were threaded stems with bolted handlebar plates.

Comment: Ok I’ll rework it, are there any threadless stem designs without removable handlebar clamp plates?

Comment: I personally have never seen one. I doubt they exist in great numbers as the advantage of removable plates became apparent in the period threaded steerers disappearead.

Comment: In which case I see it as relevant, however the paragraph is trying to make two points and maybe not making either very well so will rework. Thanks

Comment: My previous comment was referencing "are there any threadless stem designs without removable handlebar clamp plates?", not the reverse, which is not uncommon. See http://www.origin8.bike/skills/components/?pirenko_portfolios=Stems The modifications to the paragraph are great though.

Comment: @GabrielC. sure, that's how I understood you, we're on the same page so far. More modifications to come, just not immediate

Answer (score 2):

As to the what, others have pointed to other resources.

As to the why.. From all I read it appears to be because of MTBs and the aftermarket fork sales. The threadless fork is easier to stock since it can be fewer sizes, it can be cut to fit the bike. Whereas the threaded fork has to be cut to the correct size, or rather manufactured to that size. Thus this makes it cheaper to stock the threadless forks. It doesnt sound like the right reason :D But from all I read, this was the primary reason. There are other reasons that others have pointed out, weight, stiffness etc. I dont like the reason that the larger stem makes it easier to remove the handlebar easier because [I feel they could have done that with quills as well](https://www.google.com/search?q=quill+stems+with+2+bolts&client=firefox-b&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=v8qDqd_HUBeysM%253A%252CyxsG-v8_YyhQ9M%252C_&usg=__6kWeuISRz5qx53JLn1XwKSwZ8jM%3D&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixq9me7rfcAhUbTn0KHRFNAgEQ9QEwBnoECAYQEA#imgrc=v8qDqd_HUBeysM:).. but that is an advantage for most people.

Another advantage is it is easier to adjust or assemble/disassemble. I spent weeks/months tracking down the right tool to tighten my threaded headset, but threadless are typically fastened with very common hex key size screws.

But I am not convinced of the original reason either because all the cheaper bikes have threaded stems :D. Although it might be that standard designs such as MTB and road are easier to use with the threadless design, whereas the threaded system allows for more variety such as my foldie.

I was curious about this.. because I find the whole adjust the height with spacers concept very hacky. Spacers are typically used in other places to hack stuff that dont otherwise fit after all..

Comment: It should also be threadless headset (or steerer), the stems ,specifically, of both styles are extensively using "threads"

Comment: Cheaper bikes have threaded stems because they are awful and buyers can be charged higher price for better solution even if it is cheaper to produce. Also, BSO buyers like to raise the handlebars and that is the one thing quill stem is good at.

Comment: What weird tool did you need for your quill stem adjustment?  A long 6 or 8mm hex tool is all I've needed generally for most, but one had an external bolthead and one needed a super long 10mm hex driver.

Comment: @Criggie the headset not the stem. I needed a 32 or 34 mm spanner (two of them actually) specially made for the use, ended up with getting some mechanics at a bike race take a look. Even they didnt know they had that spanner!!

Comment: I had play in my headset (rock front and back) and thus needed tightening.